# Changing Active Directory passwords always fails on password complexity

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, .net-3.5

I'm trying to give my SharePoint 2010 users to change their AD passwords using the following C# on an application page (.aspx):

```
using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
{
    ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);

    if (user != null)
    {
        user.ChangePassword(oldPw, newPw);
        user.Save();
    }
}
```

Which works fine on my development environment. On the production environment however, regardless of the new password and the password policy set in gpmc, I always get the following exception

> System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PasswordException: The
>   password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the
>   minimum password length, password complexity and password history
>   requirements. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708C5)

I've tried using the "old" method of:

```
directoryEntry.Invoke("ChangePassword", oldPassword, newPassword); 
directoryEntry.Commit();
```

but that gives the same exception.

This has completely stumped me - the only possible reasons I can think of are that either the code needs to run on a box that is a DC (hence why it works on development but not production) or because SharePoint is configured slightly differently.

Comment: have you checked the configuration on sharepoint? Could it be due to Minimum Password Age? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736605%28v=WS.10%29.aspx Are there any undefined policies?

Comment: What configuration on SharePoint? I've set the minimum password age to 0, so passwords can be changed any time. I've also set the number of remembered passwords to 0, and removed the requirement for the password to meet the complexity requirements.

Comment: Did you remember to run gpupdate after you changed the gpedit policies on production?  They do not update until you run GPUpdate.

Comment: Ah, no. I was under the impression that gpupdate was only needed if using gpedit, not gpmc.

Comment: I've run gpupdate so those changes should have taken effect, but I'm still getting the same exception. Does the server on which the code is running need the Active Directory Administrative Center feature installed?

Answer (score 3):

Better late than never...

One of the following Microsoft patches released in December 2015, or the combination of them, contained a bug that would cause a spurrious throw of the above error, even though the password was actually changed successfully.

- Security Update  KB3142024
- Security Update  KB3156016
- Security Update  KB3153171
- Security Update  KB3156019
- Security Update  KB3156013
- Security Update  KB3153199
- Security Update  KB3156017

MS has told our company that it is fixed by applying the applicable ones of these later patches:

- 3126587 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126587
- 3126593 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3126593
- 3140410 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3140410
- 3156417 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3156417

The rather horrible alternative workaround is to record the user.LastPasswordSet() DateTime, put the password change in a try/catch for the specific error, and on catch, see if the user.LastPasswordSet() has changed... if it has, swallow the error.  I refuse to post code for this horrible workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity error is also returned if an attempt is made to change the password before the 'Password changeable' date has been reached (default: 24 hours after successful password change/reset).

[image: net user %username% /domain screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the password you are trying to set "meet the password policy requirements".

Password must meet complexity requirements
Description
This security setting determines whether passwords must meet complexity requirements. Complexity requirements are enforced when passwords are changed or created.
If this policy is enabled, passwords must meet the following minimum requirements when they are changed or created:
Passwords must not contain the user's entire samAccountName (Account Name) value or entire displayName (Full Name) value. Both checks are not case sensitive:

The samAccountName is checked in its entirety only to determine whether it is part of the password. If the samAccountName is less than three characters long, this check is skipped.

The displayName is parsed for delimiters: commas, periods, dashes or hyphens, underscores, spaces, pound signs, and tabs. If any of these delimiters are found, the displayName is split and all parsed sections (tokens) are confirmed not to be included in the password. Tokens that are less than three characters in length are ignored, and substrings of the tokens are not checked. For example, the name "Erin M. Hagens" is split into three tokens: "Erin," "M," and "Hagens." Because the second token is only one character long, it is ignored. Therefore, this user could not have a password that included either "erin" or "hagens" as a substring anywhere in the password.

Passwords must contain characters from three of the following five categories:

Uppercase characters of European languages (A through Z, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)

Lowercase characters of European languages (a through z, sharp-s, with diacritic marks, Greek and Cyrillic characters)

Base 10 digits (0 through 9)

Nonalphanumeric characters: ~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/

Any Unicode character that is categorized as an alphabetic character but is not uppercase or lowercase. This includes Unicode characters from Asian languages.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786468(v=ws.10).aspx